# Find element in Java HashMap<String, String[]>

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm having trouble to find an element inside my String array contained inside my HashMap. I have a String that is indeed inside this String[] but doing the following does not work.

```java
if (groupOuMap.containsValue("someString")) {
     groupOu = "someString";
}
```

My goal is to find the corresponding key of my HashMap where the value is found.

Exemple with a sample of my map :

```
nedcard.nl -> ["Wijchen account"]
mic.ad ->  ["Ayutthaya4", "Brazil", "Changi", "Dresden", "Guangzhou"]
```

If I search for the String `Brazil`, I'd like to have a new Array of String which would be :

```
String[] groupOu = {"mic.ad", "Brazil"};
```

I have tried to used `groupOuMap.values().contains()` as well with no success.

Am I doing this wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Please show more of your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your values are arrays, not strings. So none of the values can be equal to `"someString"` for example. You might want to rethink your structure if this is a necessary operation. Otherwise if you have to use this structure, then you would have to iterate through the values and check whether each `String[]` had an element that matches.

Comment: You can iterate over entries(key-value pairs) of your map and look for the value then return the key.

Comment: What if that String can be found in more than one array for multiple keys, which key should be returned then? All of them? The first fitting found?

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu I tried to iterate over entries but didn't work, I think as Henry Twist said my values are arrays and not string.

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS This can't happen, the String can only be found once from my imported values.

Comment: Would you consider a `Map<String, List<String>>` it doesn't change much, but List has a 'contains' method that will be a bit more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java the easiest way to do this is probably just to iterate through each key-value pair in the map, and search for the first occurrence of the search term in the array that is the value. When found, return both the key and the value. If not found, return `null`.

```
public static String[] keyContainingValue(HashMap<String, String[]> map, String searchFor) {
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        String[] values = map.get(key);
        // construct for replicating List.contains() on a primitive array
        if (Arrays.stream(values).anyMatch(i -> i.equals(searchFor))) {
            return {key, searchFor};
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` over the `entrySet` via `Stream`s.

```
public static String[] search(Map<String, String[]> map, String value){
    return map.entrySet().stream()
      .filter(e -> Arrays.stream(e.getValue()).anyMatch(value::equals))
      .findAny().map(e -> new String[]{e.getKey(), value}).orElse(null);
}
//...
Map<String, String[]> map = Map.of("mic.ad", new String[]{"Ayutthaya4", "Brazil", "Changi", "Dresden", "Guangzhou"}, "nedcard.nl", new String[]{"Wijchen account"});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(search(map, "Brazil"))); // [mic.ad, Brazil]
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/vPfqwl)